# Angular 4 Accessing dom of another component inside routering component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created toolbar and related components in my app

So here is layout I have created

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div>
        <app-platformbar ></app-platformbar>
    </div>
    <div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

platforbar component is common for all routing

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" >
    <span><h2>{{Name}}</h2></span>
    <span *ngIf="showLogoutBtn"><button md-raised-button color="warn" (click)="logout()">Logout</button></span>
</md-toolbar>
```

Inside **platforBar** component I have created one logout button which I don't want show on login( component) router

I have stored user object inside **userservice** to identify whether the user is logged in or not.

based on logged in I want to hide logout button.

So what I want to once user click on logout button from home router It will redirect it to login router but logout button from platformbar component is still there

So I want to hide it on login router.

Comment: does the value of `showLogoutBtn` change

Comment: I want to change the same value of showLogoutBtn from login component

Comment: why not go for a shared service and inform the login component of the change when logout is clicked

Comment: `plaforbar` component is loading just first time. so while logging out how I can I get access to `showLogoutBtn` and change value

Comment: make use of shared services, when loggin out you will change the value in th service which will notify the platformbar component of the change , please check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) question 2